# Problemas al hacer un INSERT con php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario de registro y para introducir los datos en la BDD tengo que hacer INSERT en diferentes tablas pero en la misma consulta. El código php que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<?php

//OBTENGO LOS DATOS DEL FORMULARIO
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$mail = $_POST["mail"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$passwordEncriptada = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array("cost" => 12));

require("datos_conexion.php");

$conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar con la base de datos";
    exit();
}

mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die("No se encuentra la base de datos");
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

//HAGO LOS INSERT
$registro = "INSERT INTO registro (Reg_Usu, Reg_Mail, 
Reg_Pass1) VALUES ('$usuario', '$mail', '$passwordEncriptada'); "
    . "INSERT INTO contacto (Con_Usu, Con_Mail) VALUES ('$usuario', '$mail'); "
    . "INSERT INTO datos_empresa (Emp_Usu) VALUES ('$usuario'); "
    . "INSERT INTO direcciones (Dir_Usu) VALUES ('$usuario'); "
    . "INSERT INTO usu_datos (Usu_Usu) VALUES ('$usuario'); ";


$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $registro);

if($resultados == false){

    echo"La consulta o los datos estan mal!";
    echo "<br><br>" . $registro;
}else{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["usuario"] = $_POST["usuario"];
    header("location:../login/index.php");
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Al ejecutar el código se me imprime por pantalla el mensaje `La consulta o los datos estan mal!` que obtengo de validar los resultados con la función `mysqli_query($conexion, $registro)`. He mirado que la sintaxis del INSERT sea correcta y los datos introducidos sean correctos y lo curioso es que cuando lo hago desde phpMyAdmin (copiando y pegando el mismo código y usando los mismo valores que se obtienen de las variables)

```
INSERT INTO registro (Reg_Usu, Reg_Mail, Reg_Pass1) VALUES ('usuario', 'mail@mail.com', '$2y$12$1vHoFlWYZlsrO1nVSx1X/eIVwc68dv6MorZxQMO9OMS'); 
    INSERT INTO contacto (Con_Usu, Con_Mail) VALUES ('usuario', 'mail@mail.com'); 
    INSERT INTO datos_empresa (Emp_Usu) VALUES ('usuario'); 
    INSERT INTO direcciones (Dir_Usu) VALUES ('usuario'); 
    INSERT INTO usu_datos (Usu_Usu) VALUES ('$usuario');
```

me lo inserta todo correctamente, pero al hacerlo desde el código php no.
Alguien sabría dar con una solución?

Comment: Es más que nada para que la cadena no sea tan larga y más rápida de leerla. De todos modos lo he probado sin concatenralo y sigue sin funcionar :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución sería usar [mysqli_multi_query(conexion,query)](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php) para ejecutar múltiples consultas enviándole como parámetro el Objeto conexión y la `query` que deseamos ejecutar.

**`Los datos dentro de la consulta debe estar correctamente escapados`** [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
$query= "INSERT INTO table1 (campo1) VALUES (value1);
         INSERT INTO table2 (campo1,campo2) VALUES (value1, value2);
         INSERT INTO tabla3 (campo1) VALUES (value1);"
$result= mysqli_multi_query($conexion, $query);
if ($result) {
    echo "CONSULTAS EJECUTADAS CORRECTAMENTE";
}
```